# Column flexbox not showing all items even with overflow-y set to auto

Tags: html, css, flexbox, scrollbar, css-grid

So I am teaching myself HTML and gave myself a little project that involved having a sidebar with a lot of menu items (34). To do this I used a column flexbox inside of a CSS grid. I expected the sidebar to be implemented with a scrollbar, which I did manage to do, but it cuts off the first and last few menu items and I have no idea why. I've looked all over for an explanation for this but, I can't find anything related to this particular issue.

I've tried changing out the elements I use for the menu items (h2, div, p,...) but the problem remains, even using the least space consuming element. I've looked up flexbox properties and still I can't find anything relevant.

I'm wondering now if it is even a good idea to use flexbox inside of a CSS grid. Am I missing something obvious? Is the approach I'm taking advisable?

As I said, I've just started teaching myself and I would really appreciate any feedback from more experienced programmers out there.

Thanks.

[An image of the problem with my scrollbar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TC6bb.jpg)

```css
/* General elements styles. */

body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

h1,h2 {
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: bottom;
    /* padding: 3px; */
}

/* Main CSS grid to organise the shape of the webpage. */

.grid {
    display: grid;
    
    grid-template-columns: repeat(9,1fr);
    grid-template-rows: repeat(9,1fr);
    
    
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100vw;
    align-content: center;
    justify-content: center;
    
    background-color: black;
}

.grid-item {
    border: thin solid black;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    
    background-color: white;
}

.grid-item-1 {
    grid-column: 1 / -1;
    grid-row: 1 / 2;
    
    background-color: green;
}

.grid-item-2 {
    grid-column: 1 / -1;
    grid-row: 2 / 3;
    
    background-color: red;
}

.grid-item-3 {
    grid-column: 1 / 3;
    grid-row: 3 / 10;
    
    background-color: goldenrod;
}

.grid-item-5 {
    grid-column: 3 / 10;
    grid-row: 3 / 10;
}

/* Flexbox for the main menu navigation bar. */

.nav-flexbox {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.nav-flexbox-item {
    flex-basis: 200px;
    flex-direction: row;
    margin: 0px;
    border: thin solid black;
    min-height: 50px;
    flex-grow: 1;
}

/* Flexbox for the subtopic sidebar. */

.sidebar-flexbox {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    flex-wrap: nowrap;
    height: 100%;
    overflow-y: auto;
}

.sidebar-flexbox-item {
    flex-basis: 15px;
    min-width: 130px;
    margin: 0px;
    border: 3px solid grey;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Learning Italian Webpage</title>
    <base>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="Test.css">
    <meta charset="UTF-8"> 
    <meta name="viewport" content="width:device-width, initial-scale:1.0"> 
    <script></script>
    <style></style>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="grid">
        <div class="grid-item grid-item-1">
            <h1>Learning Italian with Deep Learning</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="grid-item grid-item-2 nav-flexbox">
            <h2 class="nav-flexbox-item nav-flexbox-item-1">Grammar Notes</h2>
            <h2 class="nav-flexbox-item nav-flexbox-item-2">Vocab Lists</h2>
            <h2 class="nav-flexbox-item nav-flexbox-item-3">Verb Conjugations</h2>
        </div>
        <div class="grid-item grid-item-3 sidebar-flexbox">
            <h2 class="sidebar-flexbox-item">Subject Pronouns</h2>
            <h2 class="sidebar-flexbox-item">Present Tense</h2>
            <h2 class="sidebar-flexbox-item">Negative Sentences</h2>
            <h2 class="sidebar-flexbox-item">Conjunctions</h2>
            <h2 class="sidebar-flexbox-item">Object Pronouns</h2>
            <h2 class="sidebar-flexbox-item">Other Pronouns</h2>
            <h2 class="sidebar-flexbox-item">Modal Verbs</h2>
            <h2 class="sidebar-flexbox-item">Interrogative Sentences</h2>
            <h2 class="sidebar-flexbox-item">Present Perfect Tense</h2>
            <h2 class="sidebar-flexbox-item">Future Tense</h2>
            <h2 class="sidebar-flexbox-item">Adjectives</h2>
            <h2 class="sidebar-flexbox-item">Present Progressive Tense(s)</h2>
            <h2 class="sidebar-flexbox-item">Possessives</h2>
            <h2 class="sidebar-flexbox-item">Adverbs</h2>
            <h2 class="sidebar-flexbox-item">Relative Pronouns</h2>
            <h2 class="sidebar-flexbox-item">Imperative Tense</h2>
            <h2 class="sidebar-flexbox-item">Reflexive Verbs</h2>
            <h2 class="sidebar-flexbox-item">Past Historic Tense</h2>
            <h2 class="sidebar-flexbox-item">Imperfect Tense</h2>
            <h2 class="sidebar-flexbox-item">Pluperfect Tense</h2>
            <h2 class="sidebar-flexbox-item">Conditional Tenses</h2>
            <h2 class="sidebar-flexbox-item">Present Subjunctive Tense</h2>
            <h2 class="sidebar-flexbox-item">Past Subjunctive Tense</h2>
            <h2 class="sidebar-flexbox-item">Imperfect Subjunctive Tense</h2>
            <h2 class="sidebar-flexbox-item">Pluperfect Subjunctive Tense</h2>
            <h2 class="sidebar-flexbox-item">Future Perfect</h2>
            <h2 class="sidebar-flexbox-item">Hypothetical Sentences</h2>
            <h2 class="sidebar-flexbox-item">Prepositions</h2>
            <h2 class="sidebar-flexbox-item">Cardinal Numbers</h2>
            <h2 class="sidebar-flexbox-item">Ordinal Numbers</h2>
            <h2 class="sidebar-flexbox-item">Numerical Expressions, Telling Time and Dates</h2>
            <h2 class="sidebar-flexbox-item">Altered and Compound Nouns</h2>
            <h2 class="sidebar-flexbox-item">Articles</h2>
            <h2 class="sidebar-flexbox-item">Miscellaneous Topics</h2>
        </div>
        <div class="grid-item grid-item-5"><p>Grid Item 5</p></div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: use the browser inspector. your sidebar spans the entire screen height. as such some of the element are hidden.

Comment: Your sidebar uses a Flexbox column direction combined with `justify-content: center`. The centering messes with the positioning of the elements. Remove it and it will be fixed. Regarding grid: with grid you don't need to create an 9 column layout. You can simply define the areas. Looking at your example I'd say you have 3 rows and 2 columns. Rows being title, nav, content. Columns being sidebar and main content.

Comment: Thanks @EmielZuurbier, that solved it. I'm still curious of the conflict of the two properties but I really appreciate your help. I also see what you mean about the multiple rows and columns. I was originally thinking I wanted them to be different widths, for finer details in the project later on, but I suppose there isn't a problem with nesting grids is there?

Comment: @tacoshy I wasn't sure about that, I checked and you're right that it certainly looks like it spans the whole page, but it was contained in a grid that specifically spans only a few rows, that should have limited it to those rows only, right?

Comment: Great! And no, making subgrids is a totally valid strategy.

Comment: not if you overwrite it with flex and flex-grow. Is there a specific reason why you use flex inside the grid? totally unecessary.

Comment: I was just following a tutorial and then trying to apply it independently to my own project. I heard a line in it saying how the two could be used together (it did occur to me that CSS grid should be able to do everything flexbox could do), and so I tried it thinking it was a thing. I'm happy to know my intuition was correct.

Answer (score 0):

So the way to fix it is not using `display: flex;` and removing `height: 100%;`.
Try it and see if it works for you.

```css
.sidebar-flexbox {
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

Comment: Hi Refito and welcome to SO. This section is reserved for answers regarding the question of this post. Any questions and comments should be submitted below the question. If you don't have enough reputation, then try to answer the question as best as you can so you'll earn reputation to use the comments.

Comment: I did try the scroll option too, it didn't change anything...

Answer (score 0):

You have given height: 100vh

```css
    /* Main CSS grid to organise the shape of the webpage. */

  .grid 
    {
       display: grid;
       grid-template-columns: repeat(9,1fr);
       grid-template-rows: repeat(9,1fr);
       height: 100vh;
       width: 100vw;
       align-content: center;
       justify-content: center;
       background-color: black;
     }
```

remove height : 100vh from here and test it or you can give height: 100%